# Order by in nested SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-order-by, window-functions

I would like to have your help about a stange fact I meet while using the "order by" instruction in MySQL

Let us see the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE `test_nested_order_by` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Timestamp',
  `index_continuity_month` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into test_nested_order_by (id,timestamp,index_continuity_month) values (1,1583772141,0) ;
insert into test_nested_order_by (id,timestamp,index_continuity_month) values (1,1583708400,0) ;
insert into test_nested_order_by (id,timestamp,index_continuity_month) values (5,1583708400,0) ;
insert into test_nested_order_by (id,timestamp,index_continuity_month) values (4,1583708400,0) ;
insert into test_nested_order_by (id,timestamp,index_continuity_month) values (5,1583794800,0) ;
insert into test_nested_order_by (id,timestamp,index_continuity_month) values (4,1583794800,0) ;
```

As you see, the 0 value is set for the column "index_continuity_month" at each line.

I would like now set this value as follows : an unique value that will be incremented in the ascending order of id and timestamp columns. The table would look like :

```
mysql>  select * from test_nested_order_by :

+----+------------+------------------------+
| id | timestamp  | index_continuity_month |
+----+------------+------------------------+
|  1 | 1583772141 |                      2 |
|  1 | 1583708400 |                      1 |
|  5 | 1583708400 |                      5 |
|  4 | 1583708400 |                      3 |
|  5 | 1583794800 |                      6 |
|  4 | 1583794800 |                      4 |
+----+------------+------------------------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Or, if you prefer :

```
mysql> select * from test_nested_order_by order by id,timestamp ;
+----+------------+------------------------+
| id | timestamp  | index_continuity_month |
+----+------------+------------------------+
|  1 | 1583708400 |                      1 |
|  1 | 1583772141 |                      2 |
|  4 | 1583708400 |                      3 |
|  4 | 1583794800 |                      4 |
|  5 | 1583708400 |                      5 |
|  5 | 1583794800 |                      6 |
+----+------------+------------------------+
```

For that, I use this query :

```
UPDATE  test_nested_order_by t1,
(SELECT
id,
timestamp,
@last_continuity_month := @last_continuity_month +1, @last_continuity_month AS index_continuity_month

FROM test_nested_order_by, (

SELECT @last_continuity_month :=0
)SQLVars
ORDER BY id , timestamp) t2

SET t1.index_continuity_month = t2.index_continuity_month

WHERE t1.id = t2.id
      AND t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp;
```

But when I see the result, it doesn't seem to work :

```
mysql> select * from test_nested_order_by order by id,timestamp ;
+----+------------+------------------------+
| id | timestamp  | index_continuity_month |
+----+------------+------------------------+
|  1 | 1583708400 |                      2 |
|  1 | 1583772141 |                      1 |
|  4 | 1583708400 |                      4 |
|  4 | 1583794800 |                      6 |
|  5 | 1583708400 |                      3 |
|  5 | 1583794800 |                      5 |
+----+------------+------------------------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

I suspect that the "order by" instruction is not taken into account (and if I delete it from the query, the result is exactly the same).

We can notice that the incrementation of index_continuity_month is not done in the the ascending order of id and timestamp columns, but is done in the order in which the lines have been inserted in the table.

BUT, if I run only the nested part of the query :

```
SELECT
id,
timestamp,
@last_continuity_month := @last_continuity_month +1, @last_continuity_month AS index_continuity_month

FROM test_nested_order_by, (

SELECT @last_continuity_month :=0
)SQLVars
ORDER BY id , timestamp;

+----+------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| id | timestamp  | @last_continuity_month := @last_continuity_month +1 | index_continuity_month |
+----+------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
|  1 | 1583708400 |                                                   1 |                      1 |
|  1 | 1583772141 |                                                   2 |                      2 |
|  4 | 1583708400 |                                                   3 |                      3 |
|  4 | 1583794800 |                                                   4 |                      4 |
|  5 | 1583708400 |                                                   5 |                      5 |
|  5 | 1583794800 |                                                   6 |                      6 |
+----+------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

The result is good !

Is there anyone who could explain me what the problem is ? And more specifically, why the SQL query doesn't have the same behaviour when it is nested into another query ?

Many thanks !

Comment: MyISAM ? Why? And what's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: The primary key is id and timestamp but I deleted it from my sample for simplicity because it doesn't change anything to the problem

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter: if you are running MySQL 8.0, this is very simply done with `row_number()`:

```
update test_nested_order_by t
inner join (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(order by id, timestamp) rn 
    from test_nested_order_by t
) t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.timestamp = t.timestamp
set t.index_continuity_month  = t1.rn
```

In earlier versions, user variables are indeed a solution; however using them with `order by` is quite tricky. That is because the `order by` is usually processed *after* the `select` clause, so there is no guarantee that the "right" value will be assigned to each row. To work around this, you would need to order the table in a subquery first, then set the variable:

```
update test_nested_order_by t
inner join (
    select t.*, @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from (select * from test_nested_order_by order by id, timestamp) t
    cross join (select @rn := 0) x
) t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.timestamp = t.timestamp
set t.index_continuity_month  = t1.rn
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=384d96513612d57250ae1002f0d497e7)** - both `update` queries produce the following results:

```
select * from test_nested_order_by order by id, timestamp
```

```
id |  timestamp | index_continuity_month
-: | ---------: | ---------------------:
 1 | 1583708400 |                      1
 1 | 1583772141 |                      2
 4 | 1583708400 |                      3
 4 | 1583794800 |                      4
 5 | 1583708400 |                      5
 5 | 1583794800 |                      6
```

Comment: Many Thanks. Just an additional question : it has been said by slaakso (and I've read here : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/) that the "order by" instruction may be ignored in a subquery. Do you think that it can compromise the solution you indicated me  (the second one)? Or not?

Answer (score 1):

A subquery result is an unordered set of rows. Therefore the MySQL optimizer can ignore the `ORDER BY` in a subquery.

Comment: I absolutly did not know that

Comment: Could you please give me the doc where that is indicated?

Comment: The behavior comes from SQL standard. MySQL just follows the standard. Earlier MySQL versions (5.5?) did follow the ORDER BY in subquery. Most of the SQL databases do not even allow ORDER BY in subquery. MySQL does follow the ORDER by if you also use LIMIT (and that the limit is less than the number of rows).

Comment: OK, thanks, I found that : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/ ; I suppose that it is linked to what you mean